# How to access a specific Joomla File

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

Within an article in Joomla, I have the following code:

`(loadposition file_download)`

This line of code loads more code, but I cannot access it from the Articles page. How do I access the loadposition code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the web you are always striving to separate content from display.  Here you are just setting up the display so that when the page renders items in the file_download position will render.    That is the html for whatever is in file_download will be generated dynamically when the user looks at the page in the browser.  In the editor you are just creating html. If you save the article and view it in the rendered form (i.e. in the Joomla frontend) you will see that loadposition will do its work of rendering whatever it is that file_download asks it to render.  That is loadposition is a way to dynamically include content (which might include text, javascript, whatever) into an article.